# Trouble parsing Unix Timestamp in Android

Tags: java, android, unix-timestamp

I am having a bit of trouble parsing a timestamp string brought back from the server using JSON. I am using the following code to extract the timestamp from a HashMap and display it in the Log:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Long time = Long.parseLong(event.get("time"));
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
String event_date = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
Log.v("Date", event_date);
```

But for every timestamp I pass into this method it brings back the date 16th Jan 1970, an example of a timestamp that I am trying to parse is `1336773600` which should correspond to the 11th May 2012. I can't see what I am doing wrong here but obviously I am. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the `event` object you are using? Is it possible it is not, in fact, returning time in milliseconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unix timestamps are seconds since the epoch.
Java uses milliseconds since the epoch.

Multiply your unix timestamp by 1000 to adjust for this.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(time * 1000);
```

to convert seconds to milliseconds.